# Getting syntax error when trying to use OPENQUERY

Tags: sql-server, odbc, openquery

I am trying to do a query via ODBC to our ERP database.  The documentation guide suggests that we use OPENQUERY to send the query.

Here is my example query

```
SELECT
 Q.Part_No,
 Q.[Description],
 Q.Part_Type
FROM OPENQUERY
(
 LINKEDSERVER,
 '
 SELECT
  P.Part_No,
  P.[Description],
  P.Part_Type
 FROM LINKEDSERVER...Part_V_Part AS P
 WHERE P.Part_No = ''2712768''
 '
) AS Q
```

When I try to run that query though I get the following error

```
OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "LINKEDSERVER" returned message "[LINKED][ODBC Plex ODBC Report Data Source driver][OpenAccess SDK SQL Engine]Syntax error in SQL statement. syntax error line 1 at or after token <LINKEDSERVER>.[0]".
Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
An error occurred while preparing the query "
 SELECT
  P.Part_No,
  P.[Description],
  P.Part_Type
 FROM LINKEDSERVER...Part_V_Part AS P
 WHERE P.Part_No = '2712768'
 " for execution against OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "LINKEDSERVER".
```

Can anyone help me here?  I've never used OPENQUERY before, but I'm coping the example straight as it is in the example documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be like this

```
    SELECT
 Q.Part_No,
 Q.[Description],
 Q.Part_Type
FROM OPENQUERY
(
 LINKEDSERVER,
 '
 SELECT
  P.Part_No,
  P.[Description],
  P.Part_Type
 FROM DatabaseName.SchemaName.Part_V_Part AS P
 WHERE P.Part_No = ''2712768''
 '
) AS Q
```

Replace DatabaseName and SchemaName with your actual database name and schemaname (probably dbo)

You don't need the linked server name inside the query

Take a look at [Having Fun With OPENQUERY And Update,Delete And Insert Statements](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/having-fun-with-openquery-and-update-del) for some examples

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  I can't believe it was as simple as that.